# Is "a 30 percent representation of either gender" correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, construction

If I'm putting together a work group, where at least 30 percent of the members should be female and at least 30 percent should be male, would it be correct to say

> The group should have a 30 percent representation of either gender.

If not, what would be the correct way to say this?

Comment: Suggestion: The group should have at least 30 percent of each gender.

Comment: It's easier to say 1/3 than 30%. But, what about the other 2/3rds? Also, you want to work with the term, members of the group.

Comment: Probably want to include the word "minimum" for clarity.

Comment: @Lambie You're right! I forgot to include "at least" :)

Comment: @MikeBrockington You're right! It should be "The group should have at least a 30 percent representation..."

Comment: @Lambie Seems we're cross-posting :) Please see my comment to your answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Helen I think you put it most clearly yourself in your introduction: **At least 30% of the work group should be female and (at least) 30% (should be) male.

Comment: @RonaldSole Thanks, yes – the problem is (i) that I find it frustratingly wordy, and (more importantly (ii) that I need to include the idea of representation somehow... I learnt from Lambie that I can't talk about representation at all in this context though, so I'm pretty much stuck haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saying "either gender" could be interpreted as either 30% male or 30% female.  That wouldn't make much sense, so after a moment's thought I'd understand what you meant.

The other problem is that you don't want 30% of the gender, (several billion people at the last count) but 30% of the group.  That means turning the sentence around

> Both genders should be represented by at least 30% of the group.

> Neither gender should have a representation of less than 30% of the group.

But it would be easier to just name the genders,  say:

> A least 30% of the group should be men, and at least 30% should be women.

That is clear and unambiguous.

Comment: What if the group membership is such that 30 per cent is not a whole number?

Comment: No problem, since I specified "at least".  If there is more than one member in the group, this condition can always be satified.

Comment: Oh!! So you're saying I *can* in fact use "represent/represented" in this context?? I learnt from Lambie's various comments that I couldn't use that at all... but this is great news, since I really need to include the idea of representation somehow. The first of your suggestions – "both genders should be represented by at least 30% of the group" is absolutely perfect – thank you so, so much!

Comment: "Both genders should be represented by at least 30% of the group". is inaccurate. That means: Men and women should represent at least 30% of the group.

Answer (score 1):

Analysis: The group should have a 30 percent representation of either gender.

In specifying how many males (men) or females (women) should be in the group, it is more natural to use a fraction (1/3. 1/2, 1/4), rather than a percentage. Percentages are good for large numbers of people: **Twenty percent of the voters** decided to stay home.

Compare: **One third of the board members** voted to keep the dress code regulations.

- One third of the group's members should be women and one third, men.
- The group should be comprised of 1/3 men and 1/3 women.
- Women and men should each represent 1/3 of the group's members.

[last one added post facto]

representation is not accurate here. "either gender" means one or the other. So, that is very accurate here.

Comment: So my original suggestion simply doesn't work? Not even if I replace "either" with "both"? I really need to include representation somehow... that both genders should be represented by at least 30% (or 1/3) each...

Comment: @Helen, the word representation does not work. "Both genders should be represented" does not work. The group is comprised of x fraction of members. I know what you are trying to say but it is not effective: Men should represent 1/3 of the members and women, 1/3 of the members. That makes sense, but is not great. Each gender should account for at least  1/3 of the members.

Comment: Hm... are you saying the very sentence "Both genders should be represented" doesn't work – even without subsequent talk of percentages? I'm sorry for being a bit slow – I'm not trying to be impossible...

Comment: @Helen Yes, I am. "Both genders represented " sounds like a reporting (news writing) style and not an administrative style. Anymore advice would have to be paid. :)

Comment: :) Ok – thanks! I do appreciate that you took the time.

Comment: In this specific context "representation" has a somewhat negative connotation ("token minority") that you probably want to avoid, so "Membership" or similar would work much better.